# "Block" method because numberOfRowsInSection returns 0

Tags: php, ios, json, tableview

My .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ServiceConnector.h"

@interface PartnerTableController : UITableViewController <ServiceConnectorDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSMutableArray *allPartners;


- (IBAction)download:(id)sender;

@end
```

Part of my .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self download:self];
}

...

- (IBAction)download:(id)sender { //perform get request
    ServiceConnector *serviceConnector = [[ServiceConnector alloc] init];
    serviceConnector.delegate = self;
    [serviceConnector download];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"count allpartners: %d", [allPartners count]);
    return [allPartners count];
}
```

The problem is that `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 0, because it takes a while to download my JSON-String, create an object and put it into the NSMutableArray `allPartners`. Can I somehow block the method `download`?

Update: `allPartners` are filled by this method:

```
[serviceConnector download];

-(void)download{

    //build up the request that is to be sent to the server
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bala.com"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request addValue:@"getValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"]; //selects what task the server will perform

    //initialize an NSURLConnection  with the request
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(!connection){
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: When ServiceConnector notifies you through the delegate that it has the data you do [table reloadData]; and that's all. Meanwhile you will have an empty table and might display some waiting HUD there or do some logic like "if [allPartners count] is 0 then return count 1 and fill the cell with some special content".

Comment: please add code for download method.

Comment: Can you tell me how to call [table reloadData]; from within another class?

Comment: @demosten, add it as solution and I will accept it. It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ServiceConnector notifies you through the delegate that it has the data you do `[table reloadData];` and that's all. Meanwhile you will have an empty table and might display some waiting HUD there or do some logic like `if [allPartners count] is 0 then return count 1 and fill the cell with some special content`.